# Como usar orm de django en un projecto aparte

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo los siguientes ficheros en mi carpeta proyecto:

```
base_de_datos.db
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from django.db import models

class provincias(models.Model):

    key = models.AutoField(verbose_name="id",primary_key=True,unique=True)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutar `django-admin migrate` me da el siguiente error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Como puedo hacer para utilizar solo el ORM de Django conectado a mi DB, `base_de_datos.db` de SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ejecutar la migración con `manage.py`, por ejemplo:

```sh
python manage.py migrate
```

Con `django-admin` puedes realizar cosas de contexto global, como crear un proyecto. En la ayuda de este comando se indica que están disponibles los comandos del core de Django, pero no están configurados para un proyecto en específico.

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).